# Getting an error Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, amazon-aurora

The full error is

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I have the following datasource set up in my application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    reader:
      username: admin
      password: password
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://<aurora-mysql-reader-endpoint_instance>:3306/credentialdb
      pattern: get*,find*
    writer:
      username: admin
      password: password
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://<aurora-mysql-reader-endpoint_instance>/credentialdb
      pattern: add*,update*
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

I did google and the number one comment is

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

But causes the following code to fall over

```
public interface CredentialRepository extends CrudRepository<CredentialEntity, Long> {
}
```

```
@Service
public class CredentialServicesImpl implements CredentialServices {
    
    
    @Autowired
    CredentialRepository credentialrepository;
```

With the exception

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.opsec.shared.harvesting.fetcher.credentialmanger.repository.CredentialRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

So ho how do I get around the original exception
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

I think it may be a dependency issue i am trying to connect to a AWS RDS aurora mysql but my dependency is

```
 <!-- spring  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you added `@Repository` annotation to the CredentialRepository

Comment: Change jdbcUrl to url

Comment: Yes I  have tried it with the  @Repository annotation  and changed jdbcUrl to url. I have feeling it might be pom related a missing dependenacy

Answer (score 0):

Ok the data source is as

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://<aurora-mysql-reader-endpoint_instance>:3306/credentialdb?sslMode=DISABLED
    username: admin
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
```

Connects to the aurora db